# Excel help getting financial year from date - Many attempts

Tags: excel-formula

Spent a very long time trying to do this. I have a date column. I want to create a column for the financial year the date is in…

| Date (columnA) | Year (columnB) (what I want) |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2026 | 2026 |
| 01/08/2027 | 2028 |
| 03/04/2029 | 2029 |

I have changed the format to ‘date’ and ‘general’ but no difference.

I even have tried to split the equations out into two parts (the first one gets the month), and the second one adds a year based on whether that month column is over ‘7’ but it just takes the year from the date column again.

Additional things I have tried:

Various attempts I have made…

`=IF((MONTH(A14<7)),(YEAR(A14)),(YEAR(A14)+1))`

`=IF((MONTH(A22>7)),((YEAR(A22+1))),(YEAR(A22)))`

-some are right, (shifts but some are incorrect)

`=TEXT(A10,"YYYY") + ((TEXT(A10, "MM") >= (TEXT(7,"MM"))))`

It just adds one to the years, no matter what

Hope someone can help me out here with this, Thanks

Comment: Define *financial year*. I'm presuming you mean *fiscal year*, and that period is dependent on the company or agency. Many times, a fiscal year is the same as a calendar year (Jan 1-Dec 31). The US government uses Nov 1-Oct 31, and the company I retired from used Apr 1-March 31.

Comment: July 2023-June 2024 is one. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your attempts I noticed the following:

`MONTH(A14>7)`

A data value is stored as a number starting from `1/1/1900` being `1`. Every date over Januar 7th 1900 will be greater than 7.

If you would write it this way `=MONTH(A14)>7` it checks for the number of the month first and then checks if that's greater than 7.

So `=IF(MONTH(A14)>7,YEAR(A14),YEAR(A14)+1)`

Or `=YEAR(A14)+(MONTH(A14)>7)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have parenthesis at wrong place.

Your formula:
=IF((MONTH(A14<7)),(YEAR(A14)),(YEAR(A14)+1))

Refer to what you say, looks like you need:
=IF((MONTH(A14)<7),(YEAR(A14)),(YEAR(A14)+1))

MONTH(A14) return number of month and if it less than 7 than it returns year representation of date in A14

[image: example]